# Confused about how a particular code works for extracting values from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm working on a dataframe in Pandas that has a column comprising of list of dictionaries. To illustrate how one of the elements in column look like -

```
df['crew'][0] = [{'job': 'Director', 'name':'ABC'}, {'job':'Producer', 'name':'XYZ'}]
```

How I iterate through this to get the name of director -

```py
list1 = []
for elements in df['crew'][0]:
    for dicts in elements:
        if dicts['job'] == 'Director':
            list1.append(dicts['name'])
```

And this works. But when applied to whole dataframe, it gives me an error: `'Float' object is not iterable`

However, when I apply this function I get the desired result, but I'm not able to understand how this code works -

```py
def get_directors(dataframe):
    try:
        director_list = []
        for elements in dataframe['crew']:
            if elements['job'] == 'Director':
                director_list.append(elements['name'])
        
        dataframe['directors'] = director_list
        return dataframe
    except:
        return None
```

Why is one more loop not being written after going inside `dataframe['crew']`? Also, when I try this code independently on a particular element, it fails at 6th line demanding me to insert integer indices and not string.

Link for data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dNVpcxB8M1J7dcV4E58Bg1fqwi48UiF2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How is `get_directors` getting called?  What are its parameters?

Comment: The two are identical, except that the second one "swallows" (ignores) exceptions, so that float exception may still be happening with the second one and it just doesn't tell you.  Try replacing `return None` with `pass` to see if the error occurs.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: @Hcaertnit I am not able to understand how both are identical. If you see in my upper code, I have written 2 for loops and 1 conditional, while the bottom one has 1 for loop and 1 conditional.

get_directors will take dataframe as input.

Comment: You're right, I'm totally getting confused.  Can you post the code you're using to call `get_directors`?

Comment: @Hcaertnit sure! I'm adding the link for csv data file at the end of the question. When you open the file, you will see a column by the name of 'crew' which has list of dictionaries stored as strings. I used eval function to convert them into original format and then tried the codes mentioned in the code above to extract only the data I need (names of directors and producers). About the code I'm using to call get_directors: 

```df['crew'].apply(get_directors, axis = 1) ```

I have also tried - 

```df.apply(lambda x: get_directors(x['crew']), axis = 1, result_type = 'expanded') ```